# Portfolio optimization with CVXpy - CVX101 Boyd

Tags: optimization, finance, portfolio, cvxpy

I am working on boyd MOOC, CVX101, I am trying to do the third homework in Python and I am encoutering a few problems

We have to solve the following program

[image]

We generate the data with:

```py
# ---- Data Generation ---- #
np.random.seed(5)
n = 20
# Covariance matrix
S = np.random.rand(n,n)
S = S.T.dot(S)
S = S/np.max(np.abs(np.diag(S)))*.2
S[:,-1] = 0
S[-1,:] = 0

# Uniform weight vector
x_unif = np.ones((n,1)) / n

# Price vector 
pbar = np.ones((n,1))*.03 + np.array(np.append(np.random.rand(n-1,1),0)).reshape((-1,1))*.12
```

And what I did

```
from cvxpy import quad_form
from cvxpy import sum as cvxsum

x_unconstrained = cp.Variable(n)

constraints = [cvxsum(x_unconstrained) == 1,
               pbar.T * x_unconstrained == x_unif.T * pbar
              ]

obj_3 = cp.Minimize(quad_form(x_unconstrained, S))
prob = cp.Problem(obj_3, constraints)
prob.solve()

print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
print("optimal var", x_unconstrained.value)
```

This is the result I got

```
status: infeasible
optimal value inf
optimal var None
```

As a side note I have the solution in matlab

```matlab
simple_portfolio_data;
%% part i
%minimum-risk unconstrained portfolio
%with same expected return as uniform
%allocation
cvx_begin
cvx_quiet(true)
variable x_unconstrained(n)
minimize(quad_form(x_unconstrained,S))
subject to
sum(x_unconstrained)==1;
pbar’*x_unconstrained==x_unif’*pbar;
cvx_end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you intended to do a matrix multiply with `x_unif'` and `pbar`. Confusingly, since these are both numpy arrays, using the `*` operator will try to do element-wise multiplication, broadcasting when it can. Therefore the shape of

```
(x_unif.T * pbar).shape
```

is `(20, 20)`. So you just need to replace this with a matrix multiply. If you are using Python 3.5 or newer you can do:

```
x_unif.T @ pbar
```

otherwise this will work everywhere:

```
np.dot(x_unif.T, pbar)
```

Then you should get a feasible result:

```
status: optimal
optimal value 6.593319112947055e-06
optimal var [-0.04367061  0.14013956 -0.165039    0.11715289  0.26894204  0.19991486
 -0.18222916 -0.06746431 -0.28428226 -0.1740003   0.14624092 -0.29178846
  0.0979433   0.02320117 -0.29351406  0.06030019  0.13121461  0.14653953
  0.24223093  0.92816817]
```